# Convert FlaggedEnum in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums, bitwise-operators

I have a enum like this,

```
enum Traits {
    None = 0,
    Friendly = 1 << 0, // 0001 
    Mean = 1 << 1,     // 0010
    Funny = 1 << 2,    // 0100
    Boring = 1 << 3,   // 1000
    All = ~(~0 << 4)   // 1111
}


let traits = Traits.Mean | Traits.Funny 
console.log(traits);
```

this console will log `6` . How to do the reverse ?
If I am passing 6 .I want to get `Traits.Mean , Traits.Funny`.

Comment: If you use bit `AND` operator with the value and one of enum values you will either get zero or a positive number. Is that the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for (var prop in Traits) {
  if(Traits[prop] & 6) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the names for the defined values of the `enum` are present in the object that represents the `enum` types at runtime, compound values are not present. We can write a function that computes the compound display string:

```
enum Traits {
    None = 0,
    Friendly = 1 << 0, // 0001 
    Mean = 1 << 1,     // 0010
    Funny = 1 << 2,    // 0100
    Boring = 1 << 3,   // 1000
    FunnyBoringCustom = Funny | Boring, // Defined compund
    All = ~(~0 << 4)   // 1111
}


let traits = Traits.Mean | Traits.Funny 

function enumToString<T extends { [name: string]: any }>(enumType: T, enumValue: T[keyof T], separator = ','){
    // Predefined value
    if(enumType[enumValue]!== undefined){
        return enumType[enumValue];
    }

    let values = Object
        .getOwnPropertyNames(enumType)
        // We only take numeric values, the enum contains both direct and reverse lookup
        .filter(x => Number.isInteger(enumType[x]) && enumType[x] != 0)
        // Sort the values, so that compound values will be before their constituents  
        .sort((a,b) => enumType[b] - enumType[a]);

    var result = "";
    for(let e of values){
        if((enumValue & enumType[e]) == enumType[e] ){
            result += result !==  "" ? separator: "";
            result+=e;
            // Exclude the bits that were in this value, to treat defined compound values correcty.
            enumValue = enumValue & (~enumType[e]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
// Usage
console.log(enumToString(Traits, traits)); // Funny,Mean
console.log(enumToString(Traits, 6)); // Funny,Mean
console.log(enumToString(Traits, Traits.Friendly | Traits.Boring)) //Boring,Friendly
console.log(enumToString(Traits, Traits.Funny | Traits.Boring)) //FunnyBoringCustom
console.log(enumToString(Traits, Traits.All)); // All
```

**Edit**

As we can see the function does a considerable amount of work, we could cache the result.

We can do this, in the `enum` object itself:

```
function enumToString<T extends { [name: string]: any }>(enumType: T, enumValue: T[keyof T], separator = ','){
    ...
    enumType[enumValue] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Or we can create a wrapped version of the function that caches in a different object for each type:

```
function cachedEnumToString<T extends { [name: string]: any }>(enumType: T, separator = ',') {
    let cache: { [name: string]: string } = {};
    return function forValue(enumValue: T[keyof T]) {
        var result = cache[enumValue];
        if (!result) {
            result = enumToString(enumType, enumValue, separator);
            cache[enumValue] = result;
        }
        return result
    }
}
// Usage
const traitsToString = cachedEnumToString(Traits);

console.log(traitsToString(traits));
console.log(traitsToString(6));
console.log(traitsToString(Traits.Friendly | Traits.Boring))
console.log(traitsToString(Traits.Funny | Traits.Boring))
console.log(traitsToString(Traits.All));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am expecting 
  Mean,Funny  as result if we pass 6.
 or  1 gives Friendly 
 or  2 gives Mean 
 or  3 gives Friendly ,Mean
 or  4 gives funny 
 or  5 gives Friendly ,funny 

Expecting result I am getting in C# but I want same result in Typescript.

Comment: @Sreekumar This also works: `console.log(enumToString(Traits, 6)); // Funny,Mean` What input does not produce the expected result ? There is no builtin way to do this in typescript